# Fundamental weights for $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

I'm interested in the fundamental weights of non simply-connected simple Lie groups, and more specifically those of $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

*Is there a general method to find all the generators? or at least how many there are ?*

The Weyl chamber for $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the cone generated by fundamental weights $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, ..., $\omega_{n-1}$ where $\omega_1=L_1$, $\omega_2=L_1+L_2$, ..., $\omega_{n-1}=L_1+...+L_{n-1}$ using the notation of Fulton and Harris.
Now the weight lattice of $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is exactly the root lattice of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, and its intersection with the Weyl chamber of above is a semi-cone generated by $n\omega_1$,... and other generators.

For example, the generators of the semi-cone of irreducible finite-dimensional $\mathrm{PGL}_3(\mathbb{C})$-representations are $3\omega_1$, $3\omega_2$ and $\omega_1+\omega_2$, and those of $\mathrm{PGL}_4(\mathbb{C})$ seem to be $4\omega_1$, $2\omega_2$, $4\omega_3$, $2\omega_1+\omega_2$, $2\omega_3+\omega_2$ and $\omega_1+\omega_3$.

The elements of the intersection of the root lattice of $\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the Weyl chamber are linear combinations $k_1\omega_1+...+k_{n-1}\omega_{n-1}$ with positive integers $k_i$ such that $k_1+2k_2+...+(n-1)k_{n-1} = 0~\mathrm{mod}~n$, and hence the question of above boils down to finding a set of generators for the solutions of the latter equation.